# What is this physical filter, shaped like a shallow pyramid?

Tags: filters, equipment-identification

I was going through my parents loft (attic) and came across an old camera bag of my father's filled with bits of old junk and filters.

I came across this weird shaped filter which sadly was not boxed like the others. The others were all Cokin and this fitted in the adapter so this leads me to believe it's also a Cokin filter. The others were all self explanatory, graduated/ND/polarizer/etc, but this one caught my eye.

Annoyingly I don't have any cameras here so I can't attach the filter to a lens for a sample image.

If the images aren't clear, it's shaped like a shallow pyramid with a circular hole through it.

[image: filter front view]
[image: filter side view]

Answer (score 44, accepted):

It looks like a multi-image, aka kaleidoscope filter - specifically a Cokin #201 - I can't tell whether it's an A or a P; they're the same but different sizes.

I can't find any reference to it any more on Cokin, apparently it's long out of production, but I can find many on eBay searching just 'cokin 201' - [examples](http://www.ebay.co.uk/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p2053587.m570.l1313.TR0.TRC0.H0.Xcokin%20201.TRS0&_nkw=cokin%20201&_sacat=0)

This is the box artwork, as an example of the image it produces

[image]

Comment: So *that's* how they did those cliche photograph and video effects back in the day! I know we had very basic framebuffer systems in the 70s and 80s but they weren't yet capable of transparency effects like that... interesting.

Comment: Exactly right. I fixed the filter to the lens and this is what happened! (Also, although it doesn't matter, it's an A)

Comment: Glad to see my immediate impression (based on insane adaptive optics elements I used to design :-) ) was correct.