# What app or filter would create the blurry clone/duplication of the people in this photo?

Tags: photoshop, effect

I was wondering what app or filter would achieve the blurry duplication of the people on the right hand side of the photo, the one that's pointed to by the white arrows? If it's photoshop how would I do it?

[image]

Comment: Not a precise duplicate, but it's one of these - [What is this (physical) filter?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/88215/57929)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A [glass prism](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/99247/15871) would create this effect.

A similar type of filter is known as [kaleidoscope filters](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/88217/75526).

No additional software is needed.